# Unable to remove all classes in td with jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am trying to remove `colspan` class but it is removing only `create` class.

```
<td class="create colspan">
</td>

if ($(this).prev().hasClass('colspan') || $(this).next().hasClass('colspan')) {
    alert('yes');
    } else {
         $(this).removeClass(); 
         $(this).removeClass('.colspan')
 }
```

Comment: May be some issue is in somewhere else. Because '$(this).removeClass();' code remove all the class from your selector. Please check below link for more information. https://api.jquery.com/removeClass/ May be issue is in inside your selector.

Comment: If you want to select all your elements with class "colspan", use `$(".colspan")`. And to iterate through the selected elements, use `.each()`. And here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/TvL4P/2/

Answer (score 5):

You don't need `.` here, you just need to provide the name of your class to remove when using **[.removeClass()](http://api.jquery.com/removeclass/)**:

```
$(this).removeClass('colspan')
```

---

Actually, when you use `$(this).removeClass()`, it's already remove all classes that is inside `$(this)` element including `colspan` and `create`.

Besides that, if you want to remove multiple classes like `colspan` and `create` which is your case, then you can separate the class name by space:

```
$(this).removeClass('colspan create')
```

Comment: The code above should work. There's probably something wrong with other code that make your `colspan` cannot be removed.

Answer (score 3):

You dont need to pass class selector `.` in `removeClass()`.so use:

```
$(this).removeClass('colspan')
```

to remove both classes `colspan` and `create`,use:

```
$(this).removeClass('colspan create')
```

Comment: This is not removing all classes in td tag.

Comment: well op has not shared the removeClass code for create. he must be using it somewhere else.

Comment: But, it is specified in the question title.

Answer (score 0):

```
$(this).removeClass('colspan create')
```